# How do I increase or reduce resolution of MODIS raster in R?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm working with MODIS data at 250m resolution. After importing into R, the resolution shows 231.6564. I now want to convert the resolution of MODIS from 250m to 30m resolution or reduce the resolution of Hansen's data from 30m (which displays as 0.0002694946 in R) to 231.6564 as shown in R.

I've tried the aggregate (x, fact=) and disaggregate function in R but the files become too large and I get an error message

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1Gb.

[image: Terraclimate data similar to Hansens]

[image: MODIS data]

I'm not sure if reprojecting the raster from different sources to have the same coordinate reference system (CRS) will give me a better base to solve the problem of resolution. This will mean all my variables will have the same resolution, CRS and extent.

```
New_modis_data <- projectRaster(Modis_data, crs = crs(Hansen_data))
```

Any help with this, please?

Comment: your MODIS stack is very large, so you should probably resample the Hansen data. You can try with `gdalUtils::gdalwarp` specifying the argument `tr=c(xres,yres)` see documentation for `?gdalwarp`. An other option is to download at 30 m resolution the MODIS data from Google Earth Engine, but you need a minimum knowledge of javaScript

Comment: Are you able to resample each layer of the stack individually? Or crop the extent?